# How does one print text without unnecessary line returns?

Tags: output-formatting, fonts

I am using the command:

```
Print["A paragraph goes in here; a subparagraph goes here; etc."]
```

The output text has line returns that differ from where they are in the input text. How can I make the output text look just like the input text? And with a more readable font than the mma default?

Comment: In general, `Print` is not the right command if you want to produce nicely formatted output. It's more for diagnostic purposes. Are you insisting on using `Print`?

Comment: I am not insisting on using Print. What is the right command?

Answer (score 3):

`Print` just displays the given text. `Style` allows to format the text in a variety of styles, e.g.

```
Style["A paragraph goes in here; \n a subparagraph goes here; \n etc.",
Blue, 24, Italic, FontFamily -> "Courier", LineSpacing -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

A line break is introduced with `\n`, and the list of available fonts can be obtained with `$FontFamilies`. For an exhausting list of possibilities achievable, see the documentation for [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I applied your suggestion like so:

Comment: Style["Location classifications; \n 1 = Openings that users will \
touch frequently: buttons, usb jack, audio jack, charging ports, \
etc.; \n 2 = Openings or seams that users will touch infrequently: \
speaker holes, microphone openings, housing/mating seams, etc.; \n 3 \
= The screen; \n 4 = Surfaces: the back of the device, etc.", Black, \
14, Plain, FontFamily -> "Arial", LineSpacing -> {1.5, 0}]

Comment: But the line still breaks unnecessarily between the words "touch" and "infrequently"???

Comment: Also, the single slashes "\"above do not appear in the notebook command???

Comment: I don't have any issues with your example, i.e. no line breaking between "touch" and "(in)frequently". Although when I diminish the window size the line will break simply because they are longer than the width of the window. Try maximizing the window.

Comment: Also, when you `Export` it to a file you'll get the right formatting. Formatting in the front end is a somewhat different issue.

Comment: When I maximize the window, that line does not break. When I decrease the window size, that line breaks in an unexpected and awkward place: the lines above and below it are twice as long!

Comment: How do I use the Style command to format text in TableHeadings:

Comment: TableHeadings -> {{"(a) planned number of positive and negative test \
voltages for each device", 
    "(b) planned number of test locations for each device",
    "(c) planned number of zaps for each device", 
    "(d) planned number of devices to be tested"}, None}]

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: For future cases: (1) don't extend the scope of the initial question in the comments; edit the question accordingly or post a new one; (2) don't make prolonged discussions in the comments; (3) when posting MMA code in the comments, enclose it in the grave accents, `,  that you can find in the upper left part of the keyboard.

Comment: @Michael With the option setting `LineBreakWithin -> False` for `Style` there will be no extra line breaks, even if the with of the window is to small to display the lines completely. One can use [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) for more options (size, scrolling, scrollbars, magnification, ...). From you question it is not clear how the output should look like and how it's related to the `TableHeadings` in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need strict control on the appearance of the output, you could consider using `CellPrint` which gives you maximum flexibility.

For example, you can print a cell with style `"Text"`:

```
CellPrint@TextCell["A paragraph goes in here; a subparagraph goes here; etc.", "Text"]
```

You can print a cell with specific formatting:

```
CellPrint[TextCell[
  Row[{"The equation ", ExpressionCell[TraditionalForm[x^2 == -1]], " has 2 solutions."}],
   "Text"]]
```

I refer you to the Documentation pages for `ExpressionCell`, `TextCell` and `CellPrint` for additional examples.